# is there a way in ts to just restrict key of the object during generic infer?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

is there a pattern or utility type to allow type guard for keys during infer a object in a generic field ?

i would like to know if i can use it like this or if is there knowing approche to do similar ?

```
type Data = {
    a:number
    b:number
}

function foo1<T extends Data >(o:T) {}
function foo2<const T extends Data >(o:T) {}

foo1({a:8,b:4,c:8}) // i want error "only know key in Data are allowed" : c is not in Data 
foo2({a:8,b:4,c:8}) // i want error "only know key in Data are allowed" : c is not in Data
```

thanks for any tips or documentation you can bring to me.

Comment: Why are you using `extends` there?

Comment: The short and the long answer is no by design and there are many of the same questions answered in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant.

The `{a:8,b:4,c:8}` is compatible to the `{a:8,b:4}` so it fulfilled what the function `foo1/foo2` need.

Even you provide an extra field `c` in the parameter but the function `foo1/foo2` would never know or use such field.

It is the same situtation if you provide an instance of a sub class to a function which require an instace of super class.